# How to POST large number of table values of HTML Form to an PHP array?

Tags: php

I have a form table `mastertbl` of a timesheet web-application in which each row represents unique entries done by the employees with each row has option 3 radio button (visible to admin only) for which admin on reading the entry done by the employee, selects the radio button and after that submits the complete form (let my table has 140 entries).

Below are content of `admindashboardentry.php` with function of row and heading (contains the form tag) of the table as follows:

```
//Webpage Table Heading
                        function displayTableHeading(){

                            echo "
                            <form action='selected.php' method='post'>
                                <table border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0'>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th colspan='13'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'  style='border-radius: 8px;'><i class='fas fa-edit' style='margin-right:10px;'></i>Update</button>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>EmpID - Name</th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Start Time</th>
                                        <th>End Time</th>
                                        <th>Hrs</th>
                                        <th>Project Code</th>
                                        <th>Task Performed</th>
                                        <th>Modified Date</th>
                                        <th>Invoice Num</th>
                                        <th colspan=3>Status</th>

                                    </tr>";

                            /*echo "
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan=13><input type='submit'/></th>
                                </tr>";*/
                        }
                        //Webpage Table Row
                        function displayTableRow($row, $i, $empid){
                                $notBillable = intval( $row['Status'] )==1 ? 'checked' : '';
                                $billablePlusNotInvoiced = intval( $row['Status'] )==2 ? 'checked' : '';
                                $billablePlusInvoiced = intval( $row['Status'] )==3 ? 'checked' : '';

                                if(empty($notBillable) && empty($billablePlusNotInvoiced) && empty($billablePlusInvoiced)){

                                    if($row['WorkFromHome'] == 1){

                                            printf("
                                            <!-- record: %d -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='10' name='empid[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' readonly/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='7' name='date[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #FFBF00;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='5' name='stime[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='5' name='etime[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='1' name='hours[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='9' name='projectcode[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' /></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='30' name='taskperformed[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' /></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='12' name='modifieddate[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' readonly/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='8' name='invoicenum[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' /></td>
                                                <td><input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='1' %s/>NB</td>
                                                <td><input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='2' %s/>B+NI</td>
                                                <td><input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='3' %s/>B+I</td>
                                            </tr>",
                                            $i,
                                            getEmpNameById($empid),
                                            $row['Date'],
                                            $row['StartTime'],
                                            $row['EndTime'],
                                            $row['NoOfHours'],
                                            $row['ProjectCode'],
                                            $row['TaskPerformed'],
                                            $row['ModifiedDate'],
                                            $row['InvoiceNumber'],
                                            $notBillable,
                                            $billablePlusNotInvoiced,
                                            $billablePlusInvoiced
                                       );

                                    }else{
                                            printf("
                                            <!-- record: %d -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='10' name='empid[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' readonly/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='7' name='date[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='5' name='stime[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='5' name='etime[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='1' name='hours[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;'/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='9' name='projectcode[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' /></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='30' name='taskperformed[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' /></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='12' name='modifieddate[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' readonly/></td>
                                                <td><input type='text' size='8' name='invoicenum[]' value='%s' style = 'background-color: #D3D3D3;' /></td>
                                                <td><input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='1' %s/>NB</td>
                                                <td><input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='2' %s/>B+NI</td>
                                                <td><input type='radio' name='status_{$i}[]' value='3' %s/>B+I</td>
                                            </tr>",
                                            $i,
                                            getEmpNameById($empid),
                                            $row['Date'],
                                            $row['StartTime'],
                                            $row['EndTime'],
                                            $row['NoOfHours'],
                                            $row['ProjectCode'],
                                            $row['TaskPerformed'],
                                            $row['ModifiedDate'],
                                            $row['InvoiceNumber'],
                                            $notBillable,
                                            $billablePlusNotInvoiced,
                                            $billablePlusInvoiced
                                       );
                                    }
                                }
```

And after submitting the form `selected.php` is called which checks for the old value and new value (which admin change in `mastertbl`) and update content of `mastertbl` as follows:

```
<?php

    /* selected.php */
    /*this code file is build to perform the change of status of employee enteries form BI, B+NI, B+I
    it is only performed by admin only. There is a `mastertbl` having all the entries of employees with defalut status set to zero.
    Admin updates status based on the entries of the employee.  
    */

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset( $_POST['empid'], $_POST['projectcode'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['stime'], $_POST['etime'], $_POST['hours'], $_POST['taskperformed'], $_POST['modifieddate'], $_POST['invoicenum'] ) ){


        require 'connection.php';

        $empidarr = $_POST['empid'];
        $projectcodearr = $_POST['projectcode'];
        $datearr = $_POST['date'];
        $stimearr = $_POST['stime'];
        $etimearr = $_POST['etime'];
        $hoursarr = $_POST['hours'];
        $taskperformedarr = $_POST['taskperformed'];
        $modifieddatearr = $_POST['modifieddate'];
        $invoicenumarr = $_POST['invoicenum'];  

        echo "<p> Master Table Updated Successfully.."."</p>";
        echo "<p>Press Back button to update more tables</p>";   
        echo "<button onclick = history.go(-1); class='btn btn-primary' style='border-radius: 8px; width: 100px;'>Back </button>";

        /*$sql="UPDATE $empidTable SET Status = ? WHERE `EmpID` = ? AND `ProjectCode` LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND `Date` = ? AND `StartTime` = ? AND `EndTime` = ? AND `NoOfHours` = ? AND `TaskPerformed` = ? AND `ModifiedDate` = ?";*/

        $sql="UPDATE `mastertbl` SET Status = ?, `ProjectCode` = ?, `Date` = ?, `StartTime` = ?, `EndTime` = ?, `NoOfHours` = ?, `TaskPerformed` = ?, `InvoiceNumber` = ? WHERE `EmpID` = ? AND `ModifiedDate` = ?";

        // SELECT * FROM cip003 WHERE ProjectCode LIKE CONCAT('%', :code, '%')

        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param( 'ssssssssss', $newstatus, $newprojectcode, $newdate, $newstime, $newetime, $newnoofhours, $newtaskperformed, $newinvoicenum, $empid, $modifieddate);

            $i=0;

            print_r("Number of Rows".count($empidarr)."\n");
            echo "<br>";

            echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>EmpID</th>
                        <th>Project Code</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Start Time</th>
                        <th>End Time</th>
                        <th>No of Hours</th>
                        <th>Task Performed</th>
                        <th>Modified Date</th> 
                        <th>Status</th>                               
                    </tr>";

            foreach( $empidarr as $empid){

                $j=$i+1;
                if(isset($_POST[ sprintf( 'status_%d', $j ) ][0])){
                    $status = $_POST[ sprintf( 'status_%d', $j ) ][0]; //get the updated status value from the radio button of the entry
                    $newstatus = $status;
                }else{
                     $status = 0;  // means entry is not updated  
                     $newstatus = $status;  
                }

                $empid = $empidarr[ $i ];                
                $codearr = explode("-", $empid);   
                $empid = $codearr[0];
                $modifieddate = $modifieddatearr[ $i ];

                $newprojectcode = $projectcodearr[ $i ];
                $newdate = $datearr[ $i ];
                $newstime = $stimearr[ $i ];
                $newetime = $etimearr[ $i ];
                $newnoofhours = $hoursarr[ $i ];
                $newtaskperformed = $taskperformedarr[ $i ]; 
                $newinvoicenum = $invoicenumarr[ $i ]; 
                print_r($i."|".$empid."|".$modifieddate."|".$newprojectcode."|".$newdate."|".$newstime."|".$newetime."|".$newnoofhours."|".$newtaskperformed."|".$newinvoicenum."\n");
                echo "<br>";


                $selectSql = "SELECT * FROM `mastertbl` WHERE `EmpID` = '$empid' AND `ModifiedDate` = '$modifieddate' "; 
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $selectSql); 

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $oldstatus = $row['Status'];
                    $oldprojectcode = $row['ProjectCode'];
                    $olddate = $row['Date'];
                    $oldstime = $row['StartTime'];
                    $oldetime = $row['EndTime'];
                    $oldnoofhours = $row['NoOfHours'];
                    $oldtaskperformed = $row['TaskPerformed'];
                    $oldinvoicenum = $row['InvoiceNumber'];

                    if($newstatus == $oldstatus AND $oldprojectcode == $newprojectcode AND $olddate == $newdate AND $oldstime == $newstime AND $oldetime == $newetime AND $oldnoofhours == $newnoofhours AND $oldtaskperformed == $newtaskperformed AND $oldinvoicenum == $newinvoicenum){


                    }else{                        
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$empid."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$newprojectcode."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$newdate."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$newstime."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$newetime."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$newnoofhours."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$newtaskperformed."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$modifieddate."</td>";
                            if( $newstatus == 1 ){
                                echo "<td>"."Not Billable"."</td>";                             
                            }elseif ($newstatus == 2) {
                                echo "<td>"."Billable, Not Invoiced"."</td>";                                   
                            }elseif ($newstatus == 3) {
                                 echo "<td>"."Billable, Invoiced"."</td>";                                   
                            }elseif ($newstatus == 0) {
                                echo "<td>"."Not Seen"."</td>";                                  
                            }
                            echo "</tr>";                      
                            $stmt->execute();
                        }
                    }   
                $i++;
            }
            echo "</table>";       
        } 
        else {
            exit('error: failed to prepare sql query');
        }
        $stmt->close();
        // http_response_code( 200 );
        // exit( header( 'Location: admindashboardentry.php' ) );
    }
    /* 
        methods other than POST or POST with incorrect fields will receive a 405 error
        ~ Method Not Allowed
    */
    http_response_code( 405 );
    exit();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that `selected.php` is getting only 100 rows of my table while my table has 140 entries. Is there any change can i make on name attribute of table (which is actually making php array)? Or the size of the name attribute is limited?

below are the image of output of more rows:
Image 1: [image]

Image 2: [image]

Image 3: [image]

Image 4: [image: Is what displayed to admin to perform operation and submit it]

Comment: I have done all edit. Please suggest some path why the name attribute is not sending form post more then 100 in php array.

Comment: Check how many input params are defined in php.ini. Param name is max_input_vars.

Comment: it is hosted in 000webhost hosting provider, free hosting provider

Comment: No problem use this to check it: echo ini_get('max_input_vars');

Comment: it is printing 1000

Comment: Thanks @step, it solved my problem as i updated the max_input_vars using the .htaccess file by adding `php_value max_input_vars 5000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS i hosted in free hosting provider so i can't access php.ini but i can update its value using my `.htaccess` file.
This can be solve by updating your `.htacess` files as in my case i update it as follows

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value post_max_size 5M
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_input_vars 5M
```

The last line solved my problem. Thanks SO